# How to include POCO Library exactly?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I got a small issue.
Im working on an exisiting project known as ghost++.
Im working on Ubuntu 1404.
I installed Poco by downloading, `./configure`, `make -s` and `make -s install`.

The default Makefile looks like this:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
SYSTEM = $(shell uname)
C++ = g++
CC = gcc
DFLAGS = -DGHOST_MYSQL
OFLAGS = -O3
LFLAGS = -L. -L../bncsutil/src/bncsutil/ -L../StormLib/stormlib/ -lbncsutil -lpthread -ldl -lz -lStorm -lmysqlclient_r -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt
CFLAGS =

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
DFLAGS += -D__APPLE__
OFLAGS += -flat_namespace
else
LFLAGS += -lrt
endif

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),FreeBSD)
DFLAGS += -D__FREEBSD__
endif

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),SunOS)
DFLAGS += -D__SOLARIS__
LFLAGS += -lresolv -lsocket -lnsl
endif

CFLAGS += $(OFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
CFLAGS += -I../mysql/include/
endif

OBJS = bncsutilinterface.o bnet.o bnetprotocol.o bnlsclient.o bnlsprotocol.o commandpacket.o config.o crc32.o csvparser.o game.o game_admin.o game_base.o gameplayer.o gameprotocol.o gameslot.o ghost.o ghostdb.o ghostdbmysql.o ghostdbsqlite.o gpsprotocol.o language.o map.o packed.o replay.o savegame.o sha1.o socket.o stats.o statsdota.o statsw3mmd.o util.o
COBJS = sqlite3.o
PROGS = ./ghost++

all: $(OBJS) $(COBJS) $(PROGS)

./ghost++: $(OBJS) $(COBJS)
        $(C++) -o ./ghost++ $(OBJS) $(COBJS) $(LFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(COBJS) $(PROGS)

$(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
        $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(COBJS): %.o: %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

./ghost++: $(OBJS) $(COBJS)

all: $(PROGS)

bncsutilinterface.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h bncsutilinterface.h
bnet.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h language.h socket.h commandpacket.h ghostdb.h bncsutilinterface.h bnlsclient.h bnetprotocol.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h replay.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h
bnetprotocol.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h bnetprotocol.h
bnlsclient.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h socket.h commandpacket.h bnlsprotocol.h bnlsclient.h
bnlsprotocol.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h bnlsprotocol.h
commandpacket.o: ghost.h includes.h commandpacket.h
config.o: ghost.h includes.h config.h
crc32.o: ghost.h includes.h crc32.h
csvparser.o: csvparser.h
game.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h language.h socket.h ghostdb.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h game.h stats.h statsdota.h statsw3mmd.h
game_admin.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h language.h socket.h ghostdb.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h replay.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h game_admin.h
game_base.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h language.h socket.h ghostdb.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h replay.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h next_combination.h
gameplayer.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h language.h socket.h commandpacket.h bnet.h map.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h gpsprotocol.h game_base.h
gameprotocol.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h
gameslot.o: ghost.h includes.h gameslot.h
ghost.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h sha1.h csvparser.h config.h language.h socket.h ghostdb.h ghostdbsqlite.h ghostdbmysql.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h gpsprotocol.h game_base.h game.h game_admin.h
ghostdb.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h ghostdb.h
ghostdbmysql.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h ghostdb.h ghostdbmysql.h
ghostdbsqlite.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h ghostdb.h ghostdbsqlite.h
gpsprotocol.o: ghost.h util.h gpsprotocol.h
language.o: ghost.h includes.h config.h language.h
map.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h sha1.h config.h map.h
packed.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h packed.h
replay.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h packed.h replay.h gameprotocol.h
savegame.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h packed.h savegame.h
sha1.o: sha1.h
socket.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h socket.h
stats.o: ghost.h includes.h stats.h
statsdota.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h ghostdb.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h stats.h statsdota.h
statsw3mmd.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h ghostdb.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h stats.h statsw3mmd.h
util.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h
```

I tried to modify LFLAGS to the following line:

```
LFLAGS = -I/usr/local/share/Poco/include -L. -L../bncsutil/src/bncsutil/ -L../StormLib/stormlib/ -L/usr/local/share/Poco/lib -lPocoNet -lbncsutil -lpthread -ldl -lz -lStorm -lmysqlclient_r -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt
```

My goal was it now to use the library for sending mails:
http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SMTPClientSession.html

So I included it in one of my functions:

```
MailMessage msg;
msg.addRecipient (MailRecipient (MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT,
                                       "bob@example.com", "Bob"));
msg.setSender ("Me <me@example.com>");
msg.setSubject ("Subject");
msg.setContent ("Content");

SMTPClientSession smtp ("mail.example.com");
smtp.login ();
smtp.sendMessage (msg);
smtp.close ();
```

But when i try to compile this, im getting undefined errors:

```
ghost.cpp:1581:1: error: 'MailMessage' was not declared in this scope
 MailMessage msg;
 ^
```

What did i miss or forgot here? I'm probably working the first time with POCO.

Comment: Supposed you have included the correct POCO header, you are missing  to specify `MailMessage` using the correct namespace `Poco::Net`: `Poco::Net::MailMessage msg;`

Comment: Thats what I missed, I didnt include the header, and the ns was missing as well. Thanks

Comment: I have made this an answer now. You don't need all of that makefile stuff in your question, it's irrelevant besides showing the `-I` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use these classes from POCO, you'll need to include the header files containing their declaration, and specify the actual namespace where they are declared

```
#include <Poco/Net/MailMessage.h>
#include <Poco/Net/SMTPClientSession.h>

// ....


Poco::Net::MailMessage msg;
msg.addRecipient (MailRecipient (MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT,
                                       "bob@example.com", "Bob"));
msg.setSender ("Me <me@example.com>");
msg.setSubject ("Subject");
msg.setContent ("Content");

Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession smtp ("mail.example.com");
smtp.login ();
smtp.sendMessage (msg);
smtp.close ();
```

Comment: Thanks also for the answere.
However I got one more issue, after compiling and trying to run, it breaks directly with the following reason: `./ghost++: error while loading shared libraries: libPocoNet.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` what is missing here? I have this file in the following directory: `/usr/local/lib`